# Open source C# library to capture picture from web cam?

Tags: open-source, c#

We looked at this:

- https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit

But it appears to be rather low level and require a lot of work to implement.

Is there something that is more ready to use?

We are in .NET 4.5/4.6, and need to capture images to read a bar code. Desktop app.